# AS3: Cast Variable as Dynamic Type

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Is it possible to cast a variable as a type dynamically, where the type would be a variable of type `Class`?

Consider the following (invalid):

```
var myClass:Class = MyClass;
var myInstance:myClass = new myClass();
```

For context: I'm working in Flex (4) to create a modal manager that will control various aspects of creating modals (via `PopUpManager`) and I'd like to keep it as minimal as possible.  Components would be passed through the same functions, and rather than allowing any type of variable to be cast, eg:

```
var myInstance:* = new myClass();
```

I'd rather keep it as explicit as possible.  Granted AFAIK there is no -real- advantage to doing this, as there are checks to make sure that the argument is of type `Class` before assigning - it's more of a POC than anything.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Edit: I suppose I could do the following:

```
var myClass:Class = MyClass;
var myInstance:* = new myClass() as myClass;
```

but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the compiler can handle dynamic typing. If it could, it would be possible to implement features similar to Generics.

I think the best you can do is:

```
var myClass:Class = MyClass;
var myObject:* = new myClass();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the same as the problem you are having or not. I needed to have a class that had a child that implemented an interface. The implementing class could be any kind but I needed to save and load all of it's information.

Let's say I have a the following:

```
public interface WindowChild {...}
```

and

```
public class Window {
    public var child:WindowChild;
}
```

when it came time to save the window I saved everything in an XML blob. I found a function in the Flash player: 
`flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(value:*):String` 
The documentation says: "Returns the fully qualified class name of an object." Which means the `String` it returns will be something like `your.packages::ClassName`. When the `Window` class makes the call `getQualifiedClassName(child)` it gets something like `my.packages.structure::MyImplementation`. 
*Note that this isn't the path to the Interface `WindowChild` but rather the class I created that implemented that interface.*

When it came time to load all that information again I used another Flash function `getQualifiedClassName(child)`. This function "Returns a reference to the class object of the class specified by the name parameter." which I think is just a fancy way of saying that it returns an `Object` but it will be of type `Class`.

All I needed to do then was:

```
var childClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(childClassName) as Class; //Child class name is what was returned from getQualifiedClassName(child)
child = new childClass(); // This creates a new Object of what ever type childClass is
```

This approach will leave the type checking for run time but you can always add another intermediate step to ensure what is returned from `new childClass()` is what you want.

Hopefully that was useful.

Cheers

Comment: Ah, that's pretty handy... that may indeed be useful.  Not exactly my problem, but still may end up finding a place.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. When I expect to have more than one type passed in I do something like this:

```
public function doSomethingWithThis(something:Object):void {
    var button:Button = something as Button;
    var image:Image = something as Image;
    var list:List = something as List;


    if (button) {


    }
    else if (image) {


    }
    else if (list) {


    }
    else {
        throw new Error("This type of object will not work with this method.");
    }


}
```