# Flash Builder. Create dynamic mxml package instance

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

so, I just beginning flash builder. to the point

my app package structure:

```
index.mxml (default) <s:application/>
  [main]
    signin.mxml <s:form/>
    dashboard.mxml <s:group/>
      [content]
        home.mxml
        data_a.mxml
        data_b.mxml
        post.mxml
        and-many-more-mxml-file.mxml
        etc.mxml
```

`index.mxml` work as (something like) front controller. that will only load `main` package component (`signin`,`dashboard`).

index.mxml `fx:script`:

```
import main.signin;
import main.dashboard;

public var m_signin:main.signin = new signin();
public var m_dashboard:main.dashboard = new dashboard();

private function app_ready():void { //creationComplete
    //...service to check session...
    if(is_signed) {
        addElement(m_dashboard);
    } else {
        addElement(m_signin);
    }
}
```

success.

we assume that user is signed. then from `main/dashboard.mxml` I want to load package from `main.content.*` that defined in array.

main/dashboard.mxml `fx:script`:

```
protected var dashboard_content:Object = {};
protected var dashboard_content_list:Array = [
    ['home','Home Admin'],
    ['user_a','User Data A'],
    ['user_b','User Data B']
    //many more.
];
for (var i:int = 0; i < dashboard_content_list.length; i++) {
    var content_class:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName('main.content.'+dashboard_content_list[i][0]));
    var content_obj:Object = new content_class();
    dashboard_content[dashboard_content_list[i][0]] = content_obj; //for refference each component
}
```

each array from `dashboard_content_list` explain:

```
0: package suffix that i want to load (ex: `main.content.home`).
1: button label (for each content).
```

but the loop is still not working, always `ReferenceError: Error #1065`.

so what I want todo is:
load `main.content.*` package class and save it on `Object` in `main/dashboard.mxml`.

some of my refference (`but still not working.`):
http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2008/11/12/as3-tutorials-instantiate-a-class-dynamically/
http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/loading-classes-dynamically-in-actionscript-3.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedSuperclassName()
[Instantiate a class from a string in ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934141/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string-in-actionscript-3)
[Dynamically Creating Flex Components In ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001951/dynamically-creating-flex-components-in-actionscript)
[AS3: Cast Variable as Dynamic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065970/as3-cast-variable-as-dynamic-type)
https://delfeld.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/object_from_class_name/
http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/06/22/actionscript-3-get-a-class-reference-by-class-name/
http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2009/08/21/getdefinitionbyname-referenceerror-and-the-frame-metadata-tag/

## respons to @SameerJain

I have try:

```
import main.content.*;

//inside creationComplete
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName('main.content.home') as Class; // throw: ReferenceError: Error #1065
var o:Object = new c();
trace(o);
```

then, I try:

```
var c:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName('main.content.home')) as Class;
var o:Object = new c();
trace(c); // return [class String]
trace(o); // return '' (empty)
trace(main.content.home); // return [class home] <<< this what I want.
```

## SOLVED

**so, @SameerJain's answer guided me to solving my problem**.

```
protected var dashboard_content_list:Array = [
    /*
    index-0: the class inself <<< this solved my problem!
    index-1: the label button
    */
    [main.content.home,'Home Admin'],
    [main.content.user_a,'User Data A'],
    [main.content.user_b,'User Data B']
    //many more.
];
```

sorry for my bad english :)
thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to do is using a Flex project and try to make it work like a pure actionscript project. This is not gonna work, either make it a actionscript project or take advantage of the Flex SDK instead of trying to go around it. The Flex SDK does manage the creation of class for you, either let the sdk manage the creation of .mxml or if you want to be the one doing that make them pure .as class.

Comment: ummh, okay. any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex dont compile non used packages from your import statement. So make sure you import all the required packages and set it as a type of any variables so compiler know that we gonna use that package/class somewhere. A working example could be

```
import main.content.*;

private var dashboardhome:home;
private var dashboarduser_b:user_a;
private var dashboarduser_a:user_a;

for (var i:int = 0; i < dashboard_content_list.length; i++) {
    var content_class:Class = getDefinitionByName('main.content.'+dashboard_content_list[i][0]) as Class;
    var content_obj:Object = new content_class();
    dashboard_content[dashboard_content_list[i][0]] = content_obj; 
}
```

Comment: oke, i have add `import main.content.*` but `content_class:class` still throw `ReferenceError: Error #1065`

Comment: and did you initialize those classes, like I posted? try with blank class so you know there are no errors om classes.

Comment: I made respon for you, see my question :)

Comment: Sir, you have to define a variable with setting type to the class, like I posted in my example private var dashboardhome:home; otherwise import to main.content.home failed

Comment: so, i have to write each signle component in a variable.., mmh let me try. thanks

Comment: Yeah, just set the type of the variable, dont need to initialize it